# How to create movable and resizable graphic objects for a graphic 2D drawing application?

Tags: android

Good day, I'm learning how to develop applications for Android (API 14). I'd like to create an application in which I could create 2D graphic objects (shapes or text), select them, move, resize, rotate or select and move their nodes. A picture taken by the camera should be used as a background image. The application should be fast so that it is comfortable to work with. Could you please advise some resources where I could learn what libraries or classes should I use to achieve this? Many thank in advance. Vojtech

Something like one can see in "Smart Diagram Lite" application where an graphical object can be dragged to another place.